# How do I link Google Analytics Goal to a Google Tag Manager Tag?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, goal-tracking, analytics-events

I am attempting to setup a goal for our "Book a Demo" form on our website.

I setup the GTM and it is firing, but I cannot get my Google Analytics Goal to recognize the tag that I have setup. I don't fully understand the "Category, Action, and Label" options under "Events," but I set it up using other guides I found online.

I'm attaching screenshots of my settings to get some help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks correct. Have you verified that the event is triggered realtime in GA?

Comment: If you aren't using the event value for anything you can un-tick the box Use event value as the goal value for the conversion.

Comment: @Kristian How do I verify that the event is triggered real-time in GA? I'm in the real-time Events area in GA, but I'm not seeing anything. 

I installed this in our External Traffic view, and we haven't gotten any demo requests yet so maybe that's it.

Comment: Alright. But do you know if the GTM trigger is firing when Booking a demo?  If the gtm tigger isn't firing, then gtm will never send the event to GA and you will not see any goal completions.

Comment: @Kristian Yes, using the Preview tool in GTM, I verified that the tag is indeed firing when I submit a demo request.

Comment: Alright so we know that the tag fires and we know that no events appear in GA? That means.. either you have an error in the tag so it can't pass data to GA, or you have a filter in GA which removes your events from being recorded by GA. That's what I would look into.

Comment: How did it go? Did you figure out what was wrong? Do you need assistance?

Comment: Hey Kristian. I did figure it out. The same Hubspot form would create different ID's for every page it created. So I had to track it by a different form ID. Anyways, thanks for your help!

Comment: That happens sometimes. Great to hear that you figured it out and got it working.